# How to test controller actions that require a current session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

I'm adding more controllers to the admin section of the Padrino but I can't workout how to stub the current user or a session with Factory Girl or Mocha.

What is a good way for testing controller actions that need a current session?

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Comment: At the moment using Rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seem to work

```
def set_current_user(user)
    ApplicationController.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
    session[:identity_id] = user.id
end
```

Comment: There is no ApplicationController for Padrino.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I've not used Padrino, and you've not given any code you've tried, so this is quite general and vague.

---

#### Alternative 1

Don't stub the session, instead use a testing framework like Capybara that sets up a cookie jar for you. Use an [RSpec shared_context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) with `before` and `after` blocks that run the login.

I don't remember the exact syntax for Capybara and I'll leave you to look it up, but it would be something like this:

```
shared_context "When logged in" do
  before do
    visit "/login"
    fill_in "username", user.name
    fill_in "password", user.password
    click "login!"
  end
  after do
    # log out…
  end
end

describe "Something that you need to be logged in for" do
  let(:user) { OpenStruct.new({name: "blah", password: "blurgh" }) }
  include "When logged in"
  before do
    visit "/only/authenticated/see/this"
  end
  subject { page }
  it { should be_ok }
  it { #… }
end
```

#### Alternative 2

Using `Rack::Test`, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336616/335847)

#### Alternative 3

[Here are the authentication helpers](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/0.11.0/padrino-admin/lib/padrino-admin/helpers/authentication_helpers.rb#L7), so you should stub `logged_in?` to return `true` and `current_account` to return the user double (whether that's from FactoryGirl or a `let` or wherever). That way your app won't ask for the information from session.