# Unable to read cookie in Rspec 3 via last_response

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rspec3

I am trying to read in Rspec 3.1 a cookie received after get call.
I see it is returned but the last_response.cookies doesn't exist.
How can I read response's cookie?

```
  it "doesn't signs in" do
    get '/ui/pages/Home'
    puts last_response.cookies
  end
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using at the moment causing you unexpected value returned?

Comment: Have you checked the another answer in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335183/using-cookies-with-racktest)? It might help. Good luck!

Comment: I need the responses's cookies not request

Comment: I rather meant this: `rack_mock_session.cookie_jar`. It the answer provided it seems the value is set on `response` with: `response.set_cookie "foo", :value => "bar"`

Comment: Tried it. it has empty cookies[]

Comment: Could you add the code of your action that tries to set the cookie? Which version of Sinatra do you use?

Comment: The cookies do exist in the last_response. however in a set-cookie header. I want that parsed. how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but facing exactly this same issue now, after some struggle, I've found an article [here](http://1pixelout.net/2015/09/16/setting-and-reading-cookies-when-using-rack-test/) that shares an interesting approach. As I also couldn't find any native parsed method for this, that has worked fine for me.

Basically, place this piece of code below on your `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
def cookies_from_response(response=last_response)
  Hash[response["Set-Cookie"].lines.map { |line|
    cookie = Rack::Test::Cookie.new(line.chomp)
    [cookie.name, cookie]
  }]
end
```

and you could use this to see the parsed `hash`:

```
puts cookies_from_response
```

For a cookie's value check, you could then use something like:

```
# Given your cookie name is 'foo' and the content is 'bar'
expect(cookies['foo'].value).to eq 'bar'
```

Hopefully this becomes helpful to others facing similar issues.